# ASP.NET Core - IOptions per tenant, appsetting.json per tenant or Vault

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, multi-tenant

We are currently converting a web app single-tenant to multi-tenant.

We are looking to overwrite the data contained in appsettings.json based on the TenantId (retrieved from the header, or query string, or RabbitMQ Header).

The "Tenant Identification" services work well. We got an `ITenantResolverService` which return a `TenantId`.

Currently, our IOptions are overwritten by `appsettings.json` then `appsettings.Development.json` then finally, by the environment variables.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", true)
                .AddJsonFile($"k8s-mount/appsettings.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

We are looking to add, before `environment variable`, an override based on the `TenantId`. Eg: `appsettings.tenantId.json` and at some point, from a JSON file in Vault.

Where should we get started? We've seen a lot of articles regarding "hard-coded" value per tenant. (eg: https://michael-mckenna.com/multi-tenant-asp-dot-net-core-application-tenant-specific-configuration-options)

But nothing seems to fulfill the requirement,

Comment: What does "single-tenant"/"multi-tenant" mean? Am I missing something?

Comment: An installation host a "single" tenant. So, a single client. For each client, we deploy a new app.

Comment: It seemed not a good practice to override `appsettings.json` value based on the header you get from HTTP request

Comment: if you need to perform some actions based on each HTTP request header value look at [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I'm not looking to overwrite the default appsettings.json. I'm seeking to overwrite its data using the IOptions and Configuration pipeline, as recommanded by Microsoft. I'm just having trouble figuring how to resolve the correct file (or later using Hashicorp Vault).

Comment: so you want to have several `appsettings.tenant<1..N>.config` files sitting in the same directory and apply only `appsettings.tenant<CurrentId>.config` values?

Comment: @Michael Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not getting here earlier, but here what you can try. Use files configuration provider and put your tenants configuration in files named by tenant. ASP.NET runtime will watch the files for you. Initially this mechanism was built to use file per config value, so if you want configuration objects you will have to deserialize them.

Here is how to add file configuration provider:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(confBuilder =>
            {
                confBuilder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "tenant-configs");
                confBuilder.AddKeyPerFile(path, true);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

You can find full sources here: https://github.com/MichaelSL/asp.net-multitenant-configs

Comment: Sorry for side question.. but can we load our JSON on a Transient basis? (per request) without using files? We use this horrible DTO now.. and I just want to split it all up into IOptions - but not sure if we can have it options "tenant scoped" like that?

Comment: @PiotrKula where are you loading JSON from? From HTTP endpoint?

Comment: Oh no its from the database. But I think I found a way to do it thanks for help

Comment: This is still hard-coded and offers no solution to a scenario in which you would like configuration to be based on appsettings.json & appsettings.tenantABC.json one time and another time appsettings.json & appsettings.tenantXYZ.json.